# Deserialize a DynamicTableEntity retrieved from Azure Table

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I want to print a DynamicTableEntity object retrieved from an Azure Table. I am not aware of the properties of the retrieved object.

I am getting an error in using Newtonsoft.Json

```
var toreturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retrievedEntitity);
```

> "Error getting value from 'BinaryValue' on 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.EntityProperty'."

How can I serialize retrievedEntity of type DynamicTableEntity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I serialize retrievedEntity of type DynamicTableEntity?

It can be done by [DynamicTableEntityJsonSerializer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicTableEntityJsonSerializer/).

```
//Instantiate serializer
var serializer = new DynamicTableEntityJsonSerializer.DynamicTableEntityJsonSerializer();

//Serialize DynamicTableEntity into Json string
var serializedEntity = serializer.Serialize(dynamicTableEntity);
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: This should probably be updated.  That package is not from Microsoft and has some mysterious dependency on Azure Keyvault (sounds dangerous)